# Is the a Product Owner the business/functional analyst in Scrum?

Tags: scrum, team-management

I would like to know what is the role of the a Product Owner in a Scrum team. I already worked in many Scrum team as developer, tester. In all teams the product owner was always the guy that created the process, explained the business with UML or other modeling tools.

Could we say that the product owner is in fact a business/functional analyst in Scrum?

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

> Could we say that the product owner is in fact a business/functional analyst in Scrum?

No. While the Product Owner may perform analytical tasks, the role of Product Owner is significantly broader and more central to the process than the typical business analyst role.

### Product Owner (PO) Role vs. Business Analyst (BA) Role

Among other things, the [Product Owner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28software_development%29#Roles) "negotiates priorities, scope, funding, and schedule[.]" Compare this to less authoritative role of the [Business Analyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_analyst), which typically will "recommend solutions that enable the organization to achieve its goals."

The Product Owner often has budgetary authority in the form of Product Backlog prioritization, and the role's ability to set goals and priorities for a project are generally much broader than the typical analyst's role of defining or refining specifications.

Some Scrum teams may actually have business analysts as members of the team. On other teams, the business analysts may be extrinsic to the team, but work with the Product Owner or the Development Team as an interface to (or proxy for) the actual end customer.

While you could technically appoint a BA to the Product Owner role, it would be a mistake to consider the two roles as functionally equivalent. In general, a Product Manager or Executive Sponsor would be a more comparable job title for the person assigned to the PO role. However, keep in mind that job titles (and job responsibilities) outside of Scrum's well-defined framework may vary widely between organizations, so your mileage in drawing comparisons may vary.

Comment: "Some Scrum teams may actually have business analysts as members of the team". I disagree with this one. A scrum team shouldn't have expert or specific roles. You team must stay agile and the role of analyst shouldn't exist. If you have an analyst in your I.T. team use him but not in the Scrum team or scrum process.

Answer (score 2):

The Product Owner is the person accountable for the product backlog. She is responsible for maximizing the value of the product and the delivered work (the effectiveness).
Furthermore she is accountable for expressing the product backlog items and one way to do this is to use UML or other modelling tools.

Bussiness Analysts or Functional Analysts or Product Managers are job titles and often when the Scrum Framework is implemented within a company, such positions are used for the Product Owner Role.

Theoretically any position could be a Product Owner, as long as she can be accountable for the following activities:

> - Clearly expressing Product Backlog items;
> - Ordering the items in the Product Backlog to best achieve goals and missions;
> - Optimizing the value of the work the Development Team performs;
> - Ensuring that the Product Backlog is visible, transparent, and clear to all, and shows what the Scrum Team will work on next;
> - and, Ensuring the Development    Team understands items in the Product Backlog to the level needed.

[The Scrum Guide](http://scrumguides.org/)